# AJAX call returning error in Outlook mail add-in

Tags: jquery, ajax, outlook, office365

I am developing a mail add-in for outlook and trying to consume a web service using AJAX and it is returning **"Access is denied"** in statusText.

Here is the code

```
$.ajax({
                url: "my-webservice",
                type: "GET",
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#content-main').html(JSON.stringify(response));
                },                
                error: function () {
                    $('#content-main').html('Bummer: there was an error!');
                },
            });
```

I tried using the same code in a stand-alone HTML page and it is working like a charm.

Can anyone tell me what can I do?